# Xcode 6 - "universal storyboard" projects will support iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, universal-storyboard

If a new project is developed using `Xcode 6` - universal story board, will it support its prior `iOS versions` (`iOS 7`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a universal storyboard on iOS 7, but you won't have access to size classes and trait collections

Comment: Wether this is documented anywhere?

Comment: All of the supporting classes, such as UITraitCollection, are ios8 only

Comment: What if i'am not using any supporting classes, doing all the things in storyboard?. Not for arguing. just for the information. Have tried like this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check once by running your app on iOS 7. There are some feature which works on iOS 8 and we need to handle for iOS 7 differently.

For eg

I created gradient colour on x-code 6, it worked on iOS 8 but not on iOS 7. 
so need to handle that too.